# How to change variable value inside overriden method of an AdListener?

Tags: java, android

How to change variable value inside an `AdListener`

I'm trying to change a variable value inside an `Override` method of an `AdListener` but it is not working.

This is under `MainActivity` class. I initialize the variable:

```
private boolean check = false;
```

Then inside `Adlistener` I change like this:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        check = true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "B Ad1 Opened!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But it's not working. When I use `check = true;` outside of this method it is working.

Comment: Not in inner class i declare after MainActivity class.

Comment: The `check` variable will only be changed when `onAdLoaded` has been called. So if the callback hasn't been called yet, `change` will remain false.

Comment: No boss to check i use toast toast is showing but the variable isn't changing@MehdiB.

Comment: @LAD Even though it is in an anonymous inner class, `check` is a field, not a local variable, so it should be possible to access it and set its value.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yeah, I wasn't on-point.

Comment: If I use any database like Shared preferences or anything else and then if i set from this method and then if I fetch the data again I think it will work or I cant set the data to a textview and then I can get the value but i don't want to extend the code thats why I try many way but failed.

Comment: Everything looks good. Make sure you are using variable 'check' after ad has been loaded.

Comment: Just based on the information there is, I can't find anything wrong. So, the problem must be something not shown in the post.

Answer (score 0):

TRY creating a method that manage to change the value of `check` variable.

```
private boolean check = false;

adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "B Ad1 Opened!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

private void setTrueCheck(){
   check = true;
}
```

keep in mind lifecycle's activity.

try using variable as volatile.

```
private volatile boolean check = false;
```